# sqlalchemy: "syncing" jsonb column between parent and child tables

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Suppose we have two sqlalchemy classes

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB


db = SQLAlchemy()

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(JSONB)

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parent.id"))
    parent = db.relationship(Parent, backref="children")
    data = db.Column(JSONB)
```

The content of `Child.data` is a dictionary `d` and the content of `Parent.data` is a list of dictionaries, one for each child, i.e. `parent.data = [child.data for child in parent.children]`.

**Is there a way to keep the two `data` columns in sync?**

---

In principle one could e.g. get rid of the `Parent.data` column and replace it with a property that simply returns `[child.data for child in parent.children]`. However, in our use case this is quite slow so we'd like to keep a copy of the aggregated data in the `Parent.data` column. Moreover, some parts of the application modify the whole `Parent.data` at once, while others modify `Child.data`.
I thought about making `data` "private" and write a setter that automatically updates the corresponding column in the other table (maybe checking if it's changed before updating, in order to avoid ending up in an infinite loop). Is there a better way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use event listeners. Something like the below should do it, depending on how your json is structured

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
@sa.event.listens_for(Parent.data, "modified")
def _parent_data_modified(parent, data, initiator):
    for child in parent.children:
        # adjust for your data structure
        child.data = data[child.id]

@sa.event.listens_for(Child.data, "modified")
def _child_data_modified(child, data, initiator):
    old_data = parent.data.copy()
    old_data[child.id] = data
    parent.data = old_data
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/mutable.html#receiving-events

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! I'll try to implement it later and let you know. Just one question, if I modify say the `Child` then `_child_data_modified` would get called and modify the `Parent`. Wouldn't this then cause `_parent_data_modified` to modify the `Child`, resulting in an infinite loop? Or does the listener actually check if the data has been altered?

Comment: Good question! I think you should be able to specify in the `listens_for` `once=True` to prevent it from firing multiple times. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/event.html#sqlalchemy.event.listens_for